# Postgres find tuples by WHERE and COUNT from other table

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, postgresql-9.4

I have two tables

**table a**
id
title
year

---

**table b**
id
a.id references a(id)

I want to get title, year and count() for all tuples with max(year). I just can't get this to work.

I can do them separate, but whenever i add a WHERE clause it fails.

```
select title, year, count(*)  
from a inner join b on a.id = b.a_id  
group by title, year
```

Something like this would give me list with title year and count. If I try to add a WHERE clause

```
select title, year, count(*)  
from a inner join b on a.id = b.a_id  
where year = (select max(year) from a)  
group by title, year
```

Here I get no tuple. I think I almost understand why, but I can't manage to solve it.

Hope someone understands me and can help!

Comment: Try outer join instead. My suggestion is that there is no record in `b` that corresponds to the record from `a` with max year.

Comment: I thought maybe i was losing tuple as well and tried outer joins and it gives me count 1 for every tuple returned.

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
WITH a_max_years AS (
  SELECT id
    FROM a
    WHERE year = (SELECT max(year) FROM a)
)
SELECT a.title, a.year, count(1)
  FROM a
    INNER JOIN b ON b.a_id = a.id
    INNER JOIN a_max_years.id = a.id
  GROUP BY b.a_id;
```

or:

```
WITH b_counts AS (
  SELECT a_id, count(1) as cnt
    FROM b
    GROUP BY a_id
)
SELECT a.title, a.year, b_counts.cnt
  FROM a
    INNER JOIN b_counts ON b_counts.a_id = a.id
  WHERE a.year = (SELECT max(year) FROM a);
```

you could also write them as `INNER JOIN (SELECT ...) a_max_years`, but `WITH` is more readable

Comment: With your last Query i get zero tuples with the WHERE clause. Without WHERE I get a full list with title, year and correct count. Thank you for input though! Maybe its me doing something wrong here.